# Kafka ACL authorization issue using Java code

Tags: java, apache-kafka, acl

I want to grant access to kafka topic through java application as we does through kafka-acls.sh. I just wanted to run below command through java api.

```
kafka-acls.sh --add --allow-principals User:ctadmin --operation ALL --topic test --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
```

I use these Java instruction to do it (topicName has test as value):

```
String[] cmdPArm = {"--add", "--allow-principals", "User:ctadmin", "--operation", "ALL","--topic", topicName ,"--authorizer-properties", "zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181"};
AclCommand.main(cmdPArm);
```

The command works without any issue. The ACL authorization is set but I have a little issue on how this command works. When I try to get the current permissions for my topic, instead of this output:

```
Current ACLs for resource `Topic:test`: 
    User:ctadmin has Allow permission for operations: All from hosts: localhost
```

I have this:

```
Current ACLs for resource `Topic:test`: 
    user:ctadmin has Allow permission for operations: All from hosts: localhost
```

You can see the difference between `user:ctadmin` and `User:ctadmin` which does not grant permissions correctly for my user, and I'm not authorized to consume on this topic.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved. It was probably due to some old data in the cache. I did a fresh Kafka install/config in another host and things worked just fine.